# Set cookie taken from the value of a text box

Tags: javascript, cookies, setcookie

How do I set a cookie with the value from a text box. And the next time I load the page the text box value is set to the cookie's value.

It should be in JavaScript.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: have you made ANY effort to do this on your own? what have you tried?

Comment: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-cookies/

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-deal-with-cookies-in-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Generally speaking, use this syntax:

```
document.cookie="username=John Doe; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2013 12:00:00 GMT";
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:
Pretty similar to what you are looking for

http://www.javascripter.net/faq/settinga.htm